C# MAUI Hybrid BlazorWebView iOS Iframe
I have a Blazor hybrid application (.NET 8) that has an iframe in one of the components.  On Android, everything in the iframe works fine; however, on iOS the site was loading externally.
I resolved that issue by setting up the UrlLoading event (below).
        private void BlazorWebView_UrlLoading(object? sender, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.UrlLoadingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.UrlLoadingStrategy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.UrlLoadingStrategy.OpenInWebView;
        }

That allows the site to load properly in the WebView now for iOS but now I have another issue.  It appears none of scripts are loaded/ran in the iframe but I can see the initial page content.  Everything works fine if I do the same as a test in a regular WebView.  This makes me think this must be some setting or configuration that can be set that BlazorWebView is changing.  Any ideas here?Thank you.

There is a related issue on GitHub: MAUI Blazor Hybrid App Fails To Load Certain IFrames #20091. You can report your situation on it.


It appears none of scripts are loaded/ran in the iframe but I can see the initial page content. Everything works fine if I do the same as a test in a regular WebView.

About this error, you can see these issues on MAUI GitHub: MAUI Blazor Hybrid App Fails To Load Certain IFrames #20091 | Ability to change baseurl #11425. You can report your situation on it and track on this issue.
